# React native app not able to ask for permission googlefit

Tags: react-native, google-fit

My react native app is able to connect to google fit in release/debug mode (deploy directly to phone / through crashlytics )

But when I uploaded to to store and download from the phone, the box asking Allow/Deny does not appear.

Even stranger that if i downloaded the apk from console and install it directly it works.

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-fit

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest, if it has the necessary permissions.

Comment: As it works in all other scenarios so I assume that I have added sufficient permissions. including FINE LOCATION ACCESS

Comment: Did you use the Google Fit APIs - com.google.android.gms.fitness